# Check if a consumed message is last or not in a RABBITMQ queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

We are using RABBITMQ Queues with C# API to perform distributed work where we have different windows application running, subscribed to a one rabbitmq queue and is working fine but we have a situation where we require to perform some operation only if its a last message in a queue. Is there any way in c# api to know whether the receiving message is the last message or not in a queue.? Something like if an application consumes a message from a queue and we get to know this is the last message and perform some operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#inspecting-queues

It gives you list of messages in queue and you can easily find last message.

Comment: we need it through c# api

Comment: also we need when a message is consumed

Comment: I used this in Python. You can check this https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html. There you will be getting Fetching Individual Messages ("pull API").

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, I would like to know why you want to know if you just pulled the last remaining message from the queue or not.